# Ambiguous Match Found in .NET 6.0 with DbContext

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

When executing this code, I get "Ambiguous Match Found" when targeting .NET 6.0, using Entity Framework Core 6.0.3.

```
context.GetType().GetMethod("Set")
```

It happens on all of my model types, and I've tried EF Core 6.0.2 and 6.0.0.

Using .NET Core 3.1, there is no problem with the same code.

Anybody else getting this?

Comment: Did you do a clean build?  All intermediate obj files must get recompiled when changing versions of Net.

Comment: `DbContext` in EF Core 6 has [two overloads for `Set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.set?view=efcore-6.0). There was [only one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.set?view=efcore-3.1) in EF Core 3.1. This is likely the cause of the ambiguity. Why do you need to use reflection to get this?

Comment: Several clean builds.

Comment: I only have a Type instance to determine TEntity, which is required for both Set overloads and the one in EF Core 3.1. That's I think why reflection is needed.

Answer (score 8):

Use the overload of GetMethod (string name, int genericParameterCount, Type[] types) when you only have a Type instance of the desired DbSet.

Example:

```
Type t = [type of DbSet you need]

var results = context.GetType()
                     .GetMethod("Set", 1, Type.EmptyTypes)
                     .MakeGenericMethod(t)
                     .Invoke(context, null);
```

This invokes the Set method of DbContext that takes no parameters, but expects a genericParameter.